# JS Like-Gate not working for all testers

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have some like gate js code that is checking if a user is logged in, and likes a particular page. If they like the page they view one html, if they don't they get another html page. It works for me, however I have two other testers who it doesn't work for. However when I log into my facebook account on their computers the like gate works. Can you tell me if facebook caches pages for individual accounts? Or direct me to the proper answers as to why this is happening? Please not my company is ROR shop so we cannot use any other server-side language like php for a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: And what does your JS like gate look like (code)?

Comment: Check this thread: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180961/facebook-fan-gate-only-work-with-admin-account-javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180961/facebook-fan-gate-only-work-with-admin-account-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the administrator user get's through the gate but not other users they get stuck in the not like section.