# facebook fan gate only work with admin account Javascript

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook fan gate in my facebook app (iframe app), but it's only working when logged in with the administrator account. When i was testing the app without sandbox mode with normal users they get stuck in the not fan section, but they are fans.
I have checked the page ID, it's correct.
Thanks for help

```
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status == 'connected') {
                var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
                var page_id = "[pageid]"; 
                var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id =" + page_id + " and uid=" + user_id;
                var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);

                the_query.wait(function (rows) {

                    if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                        $("#container").show();
                        $("#container_notlike").hide();
                        $("#notloggedin").hide();
                        alert("User like page")

                    }

                    else {
                        $("#container_notlike").show();
                        $("#container").hide();
                        $("#notloggedin").hide();
                        alert("User NOT like page")
                        login();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $("#container_notlike").hide();
                $("#container").hide();

                $("#notloggedin").show();

                login();

            }
        });

    }
    init();
```

Comment: Have the users granted you the `user_likes` permission in the Auth flow?

Comment: (you can check with a call to `/me/permissions`)

Comment: Thanks man, you solved my case!

Comment: Do you know how to refresh the app after the user click the like button?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it seems your [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) code wasn't actually asking for the `user_likes` permission which you'll need to check if the page is liked by users who don't have completely Public likes

Re: the other question in the comments, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/ - subscribe to the edge.create callback and you'll be notified when the like button is clicked